# Getting font character spacing in Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, spacing

I'm trying to get the spacing between characters for any font in Android when painting to a Canvas, and I searched in Google but couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to get the font character spacing?

Comment: space in what context you talking?

Comment: @hotveryspicy in canvas if that what you meant

Answer (score 1):

I am prepared to make a WAG that what this use-case really needs is methods more along the lines of:

- [`Paint.getTextBounds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)
- [`Paint.getTextWidths()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextWidths%28java.lang.String,%20float%5b%5d%29)

Both those methods are overloaded.  The link is to the one that appears first in the docs.

Possibly the reason you have not found the information on the distance between characters is that for most purposes it is irrelevant.  What is relevant is the final width of the rendered text, or it's bounds.

> does this work with canvas ?

I was looking through the [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#pubmethods) for [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)<sup>1</sup> when I saw it!  To underline that, I am new to Android, but experienced at using standard desktop Java (J2SE).  In J2SE, I've never once heard a question in relation to the spacing between characters.  Many, many questions about the width or the bounds.

But definitely examine the same docs I have been looking at, do a search on 'paint' and find the ways in which it can be used when rendering text.

1. The **Developer Guides** link at the top of that document would also be very helpful to you at this moment.  They tend to cover these sorts of things.

Comment: thanks, exactly I wanted the width of specific letters in the text, and I think you you meant this too ? so I'm going to try and let you know later :)